# Counting values

Tags: python, pandas

I work with Pandas data frame. I want to count data by one column. You can see example below:

```
data = {'name': ['Company1', 'Company2', 'Company1', 'Company2', 'Company1'], 
        'employee': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'employee'])
df
```

Now I want to count all employees from column employee into new column. I try to do this with this line of code

```
 df['employees']=df.groupby(['name']).agg({'employee':np.count,})
```

But after execution this line of code I got this error:

```
module 'numpy' has no attribute 'count'
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: You are probably looking for `size` or `sum`

Comment: and `transform`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df['employee'] = df.groupby('name')['employee'].transform('count')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       name  employee
0  Company1         3
1  Company2         2
2  Company1         3
3  Company2         2
4  Company1         3
```

Comment: does using map slow down the process anyway

Comment: @gilf0yle I'm not really sure...I once saw a post where `replace` was faster than `map`, but I'm not sure about here. Anyway, your answer is good, I'll upvote it tomorrow since I'm out of votes :|

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on my understanding of the question. please be clear and crisp from next time you ask a question.
initial Dataframe:

```
       name  employee
0  Company1         1
1  Company2         1
2  Company1         1
3  Company2         1
4  Company1         1
```

use this

```
df['employees']=df['name'].map(df.name.value_counts().to_dict())
```

output:-

```
       name  employee  employees
0  Company1         1         3
1  Company2         1          2
2  Company1         1          3
3  Company2         1          2
4  Company1         1          3
```